Why can't the name of a JavaScript class constructor be set in a static initialization block?
The name property of a JavaScript class constructor is read-only once the class is defined, but it can be modified by a static field definition in the class body itself. However, I was surprised to find that it can't be modified in a static initialization block.
This works great:
class Foo {
  static name = 'Bar';
}

But this throws a TypeError saying that name is read-only:
class Foo {
  static {
    this.name = 'Bar';
  }
}

Is this the intended behavior or an accidental quirk in the spec?

The first example surprises me more than the second. In the second, this refers to the constructor function object, which implies that the function object exists and thus already has a read-only "name" property.

A static property declaration uses (internally) the Object.defineProperty() mechanism (well the internal version). Thus overriding the "name" property works there, because that won't check "read-only" the way a normal property assignment does.
Thus this will also work:
class Foo {
  static {
    Object.defineProperty(this, "name", { value: 'Bar'});
  }
}


I had this in mind just now :). +1

This piece of code will work just fine .The idea I suppose is that the static elements needs to be defined before you use the static initialization blocks.
Read more here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Static_initialization_blocks


  class Foo {
    static name ;
    static {
        this.name = 'Bar1';
      }
  }
  console.log(Foo.name)




Right, the first static declaration reconfigures the property and leaves it writable (I guess).

How does this explain that it only seems to be a problem with this.name ... whereas if you replace name with whatever you don't need to define it first?
